# Bluetooth headset input mess with output - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, headset

I have been using Motorola Pulse Escape bluetooth headset with built-in mic and they've been working fine except for audio input. I can make them play stereo when the audio input is set to my laptop internal microphone but whenever I want to use my headset mic, the stereo playback stops working, it just turn to mono even with A2DP sink config. Any ideas on how to make this work?
[Stereo output working using laptop mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhcww.png) [Mono output using headset mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MrQI.png)

Pd: PulseAudio config make the mic work betterbut doesn't fix the playback issue.

Comment: I have the identical problem with my Aftershokz headset - did you find any solution for this?